# ANGULAR JS: Adding multiple factories and directives to one angular module

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Angularjs in my project and wonder if I can add multiple multiple factories and directives to one angular module like this: (after added like this, only the first directive and factory is working and show results on browser, the second not)

**app.js:**

```
var app = angular.module("quizApp", []);

app.directive("quiz", function (quizFactory) {
//...
});

app.factory("quizFactory", function () {
//...
});

app.directive("quiz2", function (quizFactory2) {
//...
});

app.factory("quizFactory2", function () {
//...
});
```

Comment: I don't think so. Are you able to put your case to codesandbox?

Comment: Yes, here it is : https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-dream-1dkpv?file=/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the 2nd `directive` + `factory` are not registered correctly. The problem is all about self-closing tag doesn't work correctly with custom directive as you write `<quiz />`.

There was a thread talking about that earlier https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1953. To sum up, you have to write as following to make it work:

```html
<quiz></quiz>
<quiz2></quiz2>
```

Comment: I made an example for you here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-http-v1b8m?file=/index.html

Comment: There are double buttons and only 2 of 4 buttons works when clicking on. Do you know how can I solve this problems? >.<

Comment: It looks like you didn't handle click event for button 2nd of the 1st `<quiz />`. Likewise, the  handling action for 1st button of `<quiz2 />` is missing. In order to resolve that, you just simply fill the missing actions in your both directives.